# Entity Framework Core : change column type from string to DateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am new to Entity Framework Core and I want to change a column type from `string` to `DateTime` using migrations.

The property I want to change is:

```
public string AppointmentDate { get; set; }
```

to be:

```
public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
```

Once I've made the model change, I run

```
dotnet ef migrations add appointment_date_type
```

which results in a bunch of `CreateTable` statements i.e:

```
public partial class appointment_date_type : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "JobSummaries",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                LocalChanges = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                CloudId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: true),
                SurveyorId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ContractName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                InstructionType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                SysRef = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                JobStatus = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                PropertyAddress = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                TypeName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                StyleName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PropertyPriceType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PropertyPrice = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                AppointmentDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                AppointmentWindowStartTime = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                AppointmentWindowEndTime = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                AppointmentEta = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ContactCallAheadIsRequired = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                ContactName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ContactTelephoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ContactType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ContactCallAheadLeadTime = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                IsKeyCollectionOrReturnRequired = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                KeyInformationDescription = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                JobVersion = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Latitude = table.Column<double>(nullable: true),
                Longitude = table.Column<double>(nullable: true),
                LastSync = table.Column<long>(nullable: false),
                PhotosLastSync = table.Column<long>(nullable: false),
                DocumentsLastSync = table.Column<long>(nullable: false),
                KeepJobUntil = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_JobSummaries", x => x.Id);
            });
```

Is this correct? Should it not generate a statement to alter the column type?

If not, how do I write a migration for the column type from `string` to `DateTime`?

The project I'm working on is using Entity Framework Core v3.1.22 and SQLite.

Comment: Could you provide us your Migrations folder

Comment: @Michael what do you mean?

Comment: When you use code first and run an migration, ef core generates a migrations folder containing previous migrations that were run against the database

Comment: @Michael what do you want to see?